# Electron does not run on shared folder

Tags: electron

`C:\share` is shared folder.
`C:\share\electron-v13.0.1-win32-x64`, `\\192.168.1.10\share\electron-v13.0.1-win32-x64` and `Z:\electron-v13.0.1-win32-x64` are same folder.

Electron app is launched correctly when I execute `C:\share\electron-v13.0.1-win32-x64\electron.exe` command.
However, electron app is not launched correctly when I execute `Z:\electron-v13.0.1-win32-x64\electron.exe` command.
According to the task manager, electron processes are running.
However, electron's window is not shown.

Can electron run correctly on shared folder?

Answer (score 0):

Should be safer to use it locally (from the C:\share). The mapped drives behave very differently compared to local filesystem. And their implementations can differ in their settings as well:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Time_Synchronisation

https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/issue-with-modified-timestamps-on-windows-file-copy.82649/

https://help.2brightsparks.com/support/solutions/articles/43000335953-the-last-modification-date-and-time-are-wrong

If I understand you are just mapping back your own shared folder, and overall the Windows server cofigurations felt to me more consistent, however the protocol changed over the time as well:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block

I do not understand the network sharing protocols well to give you exact answer why you have the problem, but I know enough to tell you that the mounted shared folders are not like your own local filesystem. In many cases the differences do not matter and it gives great user expierence, but in some cases these minute differences break things in misterious ways, even if they are mapped/mounted almost like a regular/local drive. This is not exclusive problem to Electron.

And that is a problem with a lot of things through SMB (mainly binaries/tools), the shared folder might be running a different filesystem, different permission and privileges (or run a completely different structure of permissions underneath if it's a completely different filesystem). Remote folders might have issues with `inotify` getting events on file updates, might miss changed file (like `touch` on Linux is meant to update date on the file), so through shared folder the date updates might be delayed/rounded. I think at one point even Makefiles were misbehaving as it was depending on the access-date to work the way it would locally.

Other problem with tools is the sharability, can it handle run multiple instances from the same location? Is it saving something into a ./tmp or some other file which could conflict with other user running it at the same time?

Overall with shares I tend to use them for data (and few times had issues with them as well), but have shared remotely applications only if they are known to not cause troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Add `--no-sandbox` argument should work.

But this flag is not safe.